# Difference between mask and bbox in geopandas read_file

Tags: python, geopandas

Geopandas read has as options bbox and mask.

https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.read_file.html

What is the difference between those two options?

Answer (score 3):

Geopandas `read_file()` allows you to subset vector data by either a rectangular area made up of 4 coordinates (a bounding box) or an irregular shaped polygon (mask). The subset will include all of the features that intersect the bounding box or mask. It is important to note that `read_file()` will not clip your input features to the bounding box or mask boundaries.